# Не запускаются проги, скомпилированные через Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

На одном из компов не запускается откомпилированные проги (Visual Studio 2015)
Visual Projects\myApp\myApp\bin\Debug\myApp.exe  отсюда запускаю (любую) прогу и она зависает в системе и ничего не происходит(курсор на курсор загрузги меняется и всё):
[image: Файл висит в системе]

Переустанавливать VS2015 пробовал
Upd: Win 8.1 рус

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению не удалось разобраться раньше в чем же было дело.
Сейчас всё исправно запускается, хотя ни библиотеки, ни VS не переустанавливал больше.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял ошибка с библиотеками, возможно нет .net

Comment: .net ставятся с VS
стоят 4.5 - 4.6
проект на 4.5.2, она стоит на компе

Comment: Может действительно есть стороннии библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

А если из вижака билдите и грузите сразу оттуда же ?

Comment: Из VS нормально запускает

Comment: странно, вы используете какие нибудь сторонние библиотеки ?

Comment: нет, только что установил VS с нуля. Он чист как капля росы

Comment: @denis проблема может быть в том, что вы в разработки используете какой нибудь сторонний класс которого нет в папке с приложением. Проблем связанных с этим может быть достаточно много. Попробуйте написать простейший HelloWorld и проверьте на нем.

Comment: любая простейшая прога. "Привет мир" в т.ч.

Comment: Попробуйте сбилдить на более ранней версии .net framework и проверить

Comment: на других тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте паблиш с указанием необходимости установки фреймворка ;)

[Как публиковать приложения из Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHYAYJwf4C8)